# Redistribution of Ubuntu 14.04 LXDE

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kernel

I wish to inquire about the intellectual property policy, where it is stated:

> You can redistribute Ubuntu, but only where there has been no
>   modification to it

As a commercial company with embedded devices, we would like to use Ubuntu 14.04.

However, it will require changes in the Kernel level as BSP developement, i.e. drivers for additional peripherals, Wi-Fi chip, etc.

That will include patches on the Kernel level relating specifically to drivers, GPIO, pin-muxing and so on.

Does this count as modification? Is this thought to be redistribution even though we do not sell Ubuntu, but instead sell a HW device running Ubuntu as an operating system?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** A community-driven website that is here to answer questions about Ubuntu but in no way affiliated with Canonical, the company behind Ubuntu.  **Therefore it's better to contact Canonical itself on http://www.canonical.com/services/contact-us to have them answer your question.**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be asked to Canonical itself, not on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you. I have contacted Canoncial. Kindly close or remove this question.